# Sample log geometric distribution from log probability

Tags: sample, geometric-distribution

I want to sample from the geometric distribution for a very small success rate. The success rate is so small that I represent it by its log. I want the result to also be represented by its log. Is there a numerically stable way to do this?

Eg.

log(success rate) = -2000

log(sample) ~ 2000

Comment: To almost 2000 digits of accuracy (assuming you are using common logarithms), your distribution is *exponential.*  Knowing that fact will make short work of the problem, because exponential variates are quick and easy to generate from uniform variates.

Answer (score 4):

Let $X$ be the number of independent trials of a Bernoulli$(p)$ variable needed to observe the first success, so that $X$ can have the values $1,2,3,\ldots.$  For any such value its cumulative probability function is given by

$$F_p(k) = \Pr(X\le k) = 1 - (1-p)^k.$$

This is readily inverted for drawing values of $X.$  That is, given a uniform variable $U$ in $[0,1],$ the value

$$x_p(U) = \lceil \log_{1-p} U \rceil = \lceil \frac{\log(U)}{ \log(1-p)}\rceil\tag{*}$$

has the same distribution as $X.$  (The brackets $\lceil\ \rceil$ denote the *ceiling,* or next greatest integer.)

**When $p$ is tiny, $X$ is likely going to be a huge value.**  This is intuitively clear: when you have little chance of success, you will likely see a very long string of failures before you do eventually succeed.  One rigorous demonstration goes like this: pick a huge number $M\gg 0$ that is still very tiny compared to $1/p,$ so that $pM$ is small.  The chance that $X$ exceeds $M$ is

$$\Pr(X \gt M) = 1 - F_p(M) = \left(1-p)^{1/p}\right)^{pM} \approx e^{-pM} \approx 1 -pM \approx 1.$$

In fact, when computing in double-precision floating point arithmetic, these approximations are *equalities* when $pM \le 2^{-53}\approx 10^{-16}.$  In other words, on a log (base 10) scale, you just won't see any values of $\log(X)$ that are more than $16$ less than $\log(1/p) = -\log(p).$

When any number is huge, there's no discernible difference between it and its ceiling (the next highest integer).  This permits us to drop the ceiling operation from $(*)$ and take the logarithms of both sides to obtain

> $$\log(x_p(U)) \approx \log(-\log(U)) - \log(-\log(1-p)) \approx \log(-\log(U)) + \log(p).$$

**That's the solution.**  Just generate uniform variables $U$ in the interval $(0,1)$ and apply this formula.  (The error in the last approximation is proportional to $-p/2,$ which is truly tiny.)

This, by the way, is a reverse [Gumbel distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gumbel_distribution).

As an example, let $p = 10^{-2000}.$  Here is a histogram of a million realizations of $X$ using this solution.

[image: Figure]

*Notice how in this simulation of size $10^6$ there were no values of $\log X$ more than $6$ less than $-\log(p)=2000.$  This is as we would expect.*

---

The `R` code to run this large simulation took well under one second, attesting to its efficiency:

```R
x <- log(-log(runif(1e6))) / log(10) + 2000
```

The three constants are `2000`, the negative log of $p;$ `10`, the base of that logarithm; and `1e6`, the number of values to generate.